# How to see that $f(t) = (t, 2t, 3t, \ldots)$ continuous in the product topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I am trying to check whether

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^\omega$ $f(t) = (t, 2t, 3t, \ldots)$ is continuous or not in the product and box topology.

But I have a feeling I don't have the necessary correct concepts to do these proofs.

I know the product topology:

1. Is the coarsest topology such that $\pi_k: \prod\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous
2. Has subbasic elements: $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times U \times \mathbb{R} \times \ldots$, where $U$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$

I don't think these are sufficient for me to check continuity of $f$...

To show that $f$ is continuous, we need to show that the preimage of $f$ is open. Take a subbasic element say: $$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times U \times \mathbb{R} \times \ldots$$
as above, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times U \times \mathbb{R} \times \ldots) = ?$ This is too abstract.

How about looking at just $f(t) = t$? Since $f(t)$ is continuous, we know for sure that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

How about  $f(t) = (t, 2t)$? Take some open set $U \times V \subset X \times Y$, then $f^{-1}(U \times V)$ is? How can I show that $f^{-1}(U \times V)$ is open? It doesn't seem to be obvious

I think if I see how this works I can generalize it to the general infinite product case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clear: the components of $f$ are continuous. Now use the universal property of product spaces.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what university property means. And yes I recognize each component of $f$ is continuous, can we explicitly write down what the preimage is?

Comment: @MSEisadatingsite Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of spaces. The universal property of the $X=\prod X_i$ is that for any family of continuous functions $f_i:Y\rightarrow X_i$ there is a unique continuous function $f:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $\pi_i\circ f=f_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subbasic open set

$$S_{V,n}=\prod_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}U_k\;,$$

where $U_n=V$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$, and $U_k=\Bbb R$ for $k\ne n$. It’s not at all hard to calculate $f^{-1}[S_{V,n}]$: $f(t)\in S_{V,n}$ if and only if $nt\in V$. If we let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be the function $g(t)=nt$, we can express this in terms of $g$: $t\in f^{-1}[S_{V,n}]$ if and only if $g(t)\in V$, i.e., if and only if $t\in g^{-1}[V]$. In other words, $f^{-1}[S_{V,n}]=g^{-1}[V]$. And the function $g$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}[S_{V,n}]=g^{-1}[V]$ is open in $\Bbb R$. This shows that $f^{-1}[S]$ is open for each subbasic open set $S$ in the product and hence that $f$ is continuous.

This is a level of abstraction that you really will have to learn to work with if you’re going to do much of any topology.